# Fixing Homebrew Warning: Directory should not end in a slash

Tags: installation, homebrew

I installed Homebrew today, and as the application suggested, I ran

```
brew doctor
```

I got this warning:

```
Warning: Some directories in your path end in a slash.
Directories in your path should not end in a slash. This can break other
doctor checks. The following directories should be edited:
    /Users/MyUsername/
```

After googling this, I opened

```
vi ~/.bash_profile
```

from terminal and manually removed the "/" after my username. So now my .bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/MyUsername
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/MyUsername
```

Then I retyped the prompt and got the same warning. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try restarting Terminal? Or at least opening a new session (tab)?

Answer (score 4):

And if you're using zsh, you'll need to edit the ~/.zshrc file and remove the trailing slash on the end of "/usr/local/bin" as well.

Comment: This worked for me; however it was an `export PATH...` in my `~/.profile` and unrelated to zsh

Answer (score 1):

After editing your profile, you have to tell the OS. From the terminal, execute the following command:
source ~/.bash_profile